# How do iOS apps know when to download new data?

Tags: ios, download, messenger

I am wondering how an app like Messenger or Snapchat knows when to retrieve new data from a server. So, for example, if my friend sends me a message on Messenger, what event triggers my Messenger app to download that new message from the server? Surely my Messenger app isn't running a script every five seconds or so to check for new content.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use push notification

Comment: Push notification is the key! Check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: NEVER use Push Notifications for Messenger kind of applications they are not reliable and have limitations, there are better ways of doing, usually a chat application works on socket connections, you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup), or [NodeJS](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an observer pattern, where you observe wether the data is changed or not. If it is changed you fetch the latest data, in your observer. 
Firebase - www.firebase.google.com works with this principle. You can check that. 
Checkout - Socket.io -https://socket.io/ too, its the base for all real time applications. 
You can also check Realm Database server -http://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/
I would recommend don't go with push notifications, as Push Notifications are sometimes not reliable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Indeed Socket.io is very useful regarding chat application, or server to many users environment.